# Can $(\log _a x)^2$ be written as $\log^2_a x$?

Tags: notation, logarithms

I actually need  clarifications on this

Can $(\log _a x)^2$ be written as $\log^2_a x$?

I actually think the latter can't be written as the former as it's likely to bring confusion to the reader.

Comment: Yes, this is the same like $\sin^2(x)=(\sin x)^2.$

Comment: It is very unusual to compose two logs (Unless you are doing like complexity stuff, in which either way people write $\log \, \log$). So the actual set of mind is that it is going to be a power either way.

Comment: I would consider it as an utterly valid notation.

Comment: If you are confused about it, maybe your reader is, too.  If so, write $(\log _a x)^2$.

Comment: I agree it is confusing, so don't use it. Just because others use confusing notation doesn't imply we also have to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the standard meaning of the notation.

If you wanted to talk about the logarithm of the logarithm, this would always be written $\log\log x$, or $\log_a\log_a x$ if the base matters and is not $e$ (often the base doesn't matter, as in $O(n\log\log n)$).

For an example of this usage, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function):

> A polylogarithmic function in $n$ is a polynomial in the logarithm of $n$,
> $a_{k}(\log n)^{k}+\cdots +a_{1}(\log n)+a_{0}$.
> The notation $\log ^{k}n$ is often used as a shorthand for $(\log n)^{k}$, analogous to $\sin ^{2}\theta$  for $(\sin \theta )^{2}$.